# Given that original Greek had no verses should Acts 13:21-23 be retranslated?

Tags: exegesis, bible-translation, acts

Given that original Greek had no verses should Acts 13:21-23 be more aptly translated to read:

> 21 And afterward they asked for a king; so God gave them Saul the son
>   of Kish, a man of the tribe of Benjamin. 22 For forty years, (and when
>   He had removed him), He raised up for them David as king. 23 To whom
>   also He gave testimony and said, ‘I have found David the son of Jesse,
>   a man after My own heart, who will do all My will.’ From this man’s
>   seed, according to the promise, God raised up for Israel a Savior—
>   Jesus— …

Comment: Tricky. David was annointed King before Saul died, so for awhile there were two Kings, the de facto King (Saul) and the annointed King (David). I believe that David's forty years and Saul's overlapped as a result.

Comment: Your question, as it stands, is unclear.  What, exactly, is the point you are trying to make? The Authorised Version clearly states that God gave them, Saul "by the space of forty years." What does punctuation or altering where a verse starts have to do with it?

Comment: The way you have re-worked it, it reads like it took God 40 years to raise up David.

Comment: @Lesley I believed the OP was trying to reconcile Acts with the ambiguity in 1 Sam 13 translation, see OP's [other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/77293/according-to-old-testament-how-long-did-saul-reign-as-king)

Comment: I believe verse division in English translation doesn't affect how the Greek version is parsed grammatically, because the sentence structure would be based on Greek grammar regardless of verse division.

Comment: You need to explain what you think should be different.